# parsing large set of json data in android (around 10k Records at a time)

Tags: android, json

Currently i'm working on an android app in which i have to parse 10k
 product information from server and to display that data in Searchable
 Spinner.
 it's working fine when on wifi but while on mobile data it's taking long time to   parse the product information.
i have used using loopj library for json parsing.

So, can anyone suggest me a better way to do that?

this is my onSuccess method where i'm trying to parse large data set and to put that in Searchable spinner, so that user can search and select product from all data.

```
@Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                    super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                    //System.out.println("Response " + response.toString());
                    try {
                        if (response.has("products_data")) {

                        jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                        jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("products_data");
                        for (int t = 0; t < jsonArray.length(); t++) {
                            object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(t);
                            retailer_id = object.getString("retailer_id");
                            retailer_name = object.getString("retailer_name");
                            product_code = object.getString("product_code");
                            product_name = object.getString("product_name");
                            pro_packing = object.getString("pro_packing");
                            pro_company=object.getString("pro_company");
                            pro_generic_code=object.getString("pro_generic_code");
                            pro_generic_name=object.getString("pro_generic_name");
                            pro_stock = object.getInt("product_stock");
                            product_MRP=object.getDouble("product_MRP");
                            p = new Product();
                            p.setRetailer_id(retailer_id);
                            p.setRetailer_name(retailer_name);
                            p.setProduct_code(product_code);
                            p.setProduct_name(product_name);
                            p.setPro_packing(pro_packing);
                            p.setPro_company(pro_company);
                            p.setPro_generic_code(pro_generic_code);
                            p.setPro_generic_name(pro_generic_name);
                            p.setPro_stock(pro_stock);
                            p.setProduct_MRP(product_MRP);
                            productlist.add(p);
                        }


       progressDialog.dismiss();
                   // Log.i("PROLIST Size:: ", String.valueOf(productlist.size()));

                    final List<String> pname = new ArrayList<String>();
                    final List<String> pcode = new ArrayList<String>();
                    pname.clear();
                    pname.add(0,"Select Products");
                    for (int i = 0; i < productlist.size(); i++) {
                        pname.add(productlist.get(i).getProduct_name());
                    }
                    // Creating adapter for spinner
                    final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_spinnertxt, pname);
                    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
                    spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // attaching data adapter to spinner

                            autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
                            autoCompleteTextView.setSelection(0);
                        }
                    });

                    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
                            if(i>0) {
                                p_id = productlist.get(i - 1).getProduct_code();
                                p_stock = productlist.get(i - 1).getPro_stock();
                                ppack = productlist.get(i - 1).getPro_packing();
                                pcomp = productlist.get(i - 1).getPro_company();
                                mrp = productlist.get(i - 1).getProduct_MRP();
                                pseller = productlist.get(i - 1).getRetailer_name();
                               // Log.i("pID:", p_id);
                                //Log.i("pStock:", String.valueOf(p_stock));
                                //Log.i("PMRP:", String.valueOf(mrp));
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                        }
                    });

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
```

Comment: you can try scroll to load more or pagination. I have implemented same for my app. Many android apps uses that technique.

Comment: Paginate the data

Comment: can any one tell me how to paginate the json data ?